# Asset Pipeline not finding JS file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

My Rails.application.config.assets.paths contains the directory for an asset I'd like (autocomplete):

```
- /Users/kiranb/application/app/assets/images
- /Users/kiranb/application/app/assets/javascripts
- /Users/kiranb/application/app/assets/stylesheets
- /Users/kiranb/application/vendor/assets/javascripts
- /Users/kiranb/application/vendor/assets/stylesheets
- /Users/kiranb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@application/gems/rails3-jquery-autocomplete-1.0.5/lib/assets/javascripts
- /Users/kiranb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@application/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.19/vendor/assets/javascripts
```

The lib/assets/javascripts for the autocomplete gem contains:

```
autocomplete-rails-uncompressed.js  autocomplete-rails.js
```

And my application.js includes:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require_tree .
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
couldn't find file 'autocomplete-rails'  
   (in /Users/kiranb/application/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:11)
```

It has no trouble finding any other assets, though.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since you solved your own question, you can write that up as an answer and accept it! It isn't recommended to put something like `[solved]` in the title of the post.

Answer (score 12):

*As stated by the original poster of the question:*

---

The problem was fixed by restarting the server.