# Rails 4.0.0 Ruby 2.0 gem "rails3-jquery-autocomplete" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-autocomplete

I have encountered the following error when trying to use rails3-jquery-autocomplete:

Initially, I used the latest version of jquery-rails but read that they removed jquery-ui. I have tried downgrading jquery-rails to gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.3.0' as recommended in this answer but it did not work. [rails active admin deployment : couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844411/rails-active-admin-deployment-couldnt-find-file-jquery-ui/17360260#17360260)

I also tried restarting my server as  suggeste din this answer but did not work either. [Asset Pipeline not finding JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857900/asset-pipeline-not-finding-js-file)

I would greatly appreciate an explanation as to how to do this in rails 4 using jQuery mobile without the gem as I have no idea and can't find any recent resources.

```
couldn't find file 'autocomplete-rails'
```

application.js

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require jquery.mobile
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery_mobile_rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
```

Comment: Hmmm, what could be the case. Wait, that's the gem name again?!

Comment: So Rails 4 is left without autocomplete? Nice.

Comment: But why use a gem if it's jquery?

Comment: Good question. I am kind of a noob and implemented this easily in rails 3.2.13. I'm not sure how to go about it using just jQuery autocomplete . It looks like there is no solution at present so i will need to go down that path. Would the controller code be the same?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this without the gem and can't find a comprehensive example for rails 4.0.0 and jquery mobile.

Comment: Check out this form, seems to be updated for Rails 4 https://github.com/francisd/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this fork https://github.com/francisd/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

In your Gemfile change

```
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
```

to

```
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete', git: 'https://github.com/francisd/rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
```

Comment: This repo does not have working rake autocomplete:install. It gives this to me:
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
to me :)

Comment: @gorn that installation step is for Rails 3.0, not Rails 4.